# How to loop through an external file using an associative array using strtok in php

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array, strtok

I am getting an infinite loop. I believe that I am reading in the same line of input multiple times instead of going to the next line. From what I can come up with I need another piece of code just above the end of the while loop that moves to the next piece. I need to do this using strtok, my question is how?

MUST USE A FOREACH LOOP, NO EXPLODE/IMPLODE.

the "include file is bbs_2013invent.php and reads:

```
<?php
$data =
"Sunscreen_SPF-55 BB-ss1 S 9.98 83 828.34 4.99 NA
Sunscreen_SPF-7000 BB-ss2 S 29.98 9 269.82 19 NA
SunHat-F BB-sh3 S 33.79 41 1385.39 25.5 NA
SunHat-M BB-sh8 S 41.79 18 752.22 29.5 NA
Sandals BB-sd4 S 19.38 32 620.16 4.75 NA
Towel-Large BB-tl S 45 57 2565.00 29.99 NA
Towel-Indiv BB-ts S 11.75 133 1562.75 5.9 NA
Beach_Chair BB-bc2 S 67.5 19 1282.50 47.5 NA
Umbrella BB-umb R 129 18 2322 398 0.4
Surfboard BB-surf2 R 135 27 3645 735 0.2
JetSki BB-jsk7 R 160.25 38 6089.50 18795.00 0.4
Outlaw20_Powerboat BB-pb20 R 298 11 3278 67850.00 0.3";
?>
```

The rest of the code is as follows:

```
<?PHP    
//Imports a file
include 'bbs_2013invent.php';
//variable
$delimiters = "\n";

//Declare and fill array
$product = ['name'    => rtrim(strtok($data, $delimiters)),
       'serial'   => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'status'   => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'price'    => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'units'    => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'revenue'  => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'cost'     => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'factor'   => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       ];

//Column headers
printf("PRODUCT  \tSERIAL#  \tPRICE/RENTALCHG   \tUNITS/DAYS    \tREVENUE   \tORIGCOST  \tNOTES");
//while loop
while(['name'])
{
//Calculates the total days rented and revenue respectively
$totalDays += $units;
$totalRevenue += $revenue;
if ($key == 'status' && $value = S && "units" <800)
{
  printf("\t L");
}
if ($key == 'status' && $value = R && "units" <20)
{
  printf("\t LR");
}

//foreach loop
foreach($product as $key => $value)
{
printf($key, $value);
}

} //end of while loop
//displays the total number of days items have been rented
printf($totalDays);
//displays the total revenue of all products combined
printf($totalRevenue);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is causing your infinite loop:

```
while(['name']){ ... }
```

This loop runs until `['name']` evaluates FALSE, which will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

One posible solution...

```
<?PHP    
//Imports a file
include 'data.php';
//variable
$delimiters = " \n";
$totalDays = $totalRevenue = 0.0;
//Declare and fill array
$name = rtrim(strtok($data, $delimiters));

$spaces = ['name'    => "-20",
        'serial'   => "-10",
       'status'   => "-6",
       'price'    => "10",
       'units'    => "10",
       'revenue'  => "15",
       'cost'     => "15",
       'factor'   => "8"
];

//Column headers
printf("PRODUCT\t\t    SERIAL#\t PRICE/RENTALCHG  UNITS/DAYS\tREVENUE\t\tORIGCOST   NOTES\n");
//while loop
while($name)
{

$product = ['name'    => $name,
        'serial'   => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'status'   => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'price'    => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'units'    => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'revenue'  => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'cost'     => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'factor'   => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       ];

//Calculates the total days rented and revenue respectively
$totalDays += $product["units"];
$totalRevenue   += $product["revenue"];

//foreach loop
foreach($product as $key => $value)
{
if ($key == 'status' && $value = "S" && "units" <800)
{
  printf("%${spaces[$key]}s","L");
} else if ($key == 'status' && $value = "R" && "units" <20)
{
  printf("%${spaces[$key]}s","LR");
} else {
printf("%${spaces[$key]}s",  $value);
}

}

print "\n"; 

$name = rtrim(strtok($delimiters));

} //end of while loop
//displays the total number of days items have been rented
printf("\n%10.02f",  $totalDays);
//displays the total revenue of all products combined
printf("\n%10.02f", $totalRevenue);
?>
```

Change condition to evaluate name value.

Delimeter token is also whitespace yo read distinct fields, and it has to read at the end of while too.

A bit to output format, and voila...